# api created in wso2 appfactory preview api publisher is not working

Tags: api, wso2

I created api from WSO2 appfactory preview api publisher. But when I call it from REST client it says the service doesn't exists where in yahoo weather api in the same api store gives OAuth error (which is expected without a token). The backend service runs nicely.

"404Status reportNot FoundThe requested resource (/usdToLkr/0.0.2) is not available."

My API is given here
http://apimanager.appfactorypreview.wso2.com:8280/usdToLkr/0.0.2
What I am doing wrong?
Is it blocked in appfactory preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, if you create an API, you have to publish it by publisher.
2. Then you have to login from WSO2 Appfactory preview and via resources page, you should click on subscribe to API and login to API store via that.
3. Then you have to first subscribe to the particular API via your created application.
4. Then the consumer and application keys should be generated manually or automataically once you click on the Renew API keys or API button.
5. Then if you have provided a working production/sandbox URL during the API creation, it should work.

If you try out with the REST client, you should provide required header values. You get an OAUTH error because you havent provided the token.

A working API invocation sample for App factory preview can be seen from [this documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AF100/Consuming+APIs+from+Applications).

Using REST client to test an API can be seen from [this documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM140/Testing+APIs).

Comment: You can use the already created yahoo api to execute the sample provided in the first link.

Comment: Yes, I get tried with yahoo api you created. I'm expecting OAUTH error but I don't get it. Instead it says the location is unavailable. Let me go through the links you provided me thorough and again comment.

Comment: Ushani, I followed all 5 steps. Yes the back-end api is up and running. I checked the back-end api with REST client and it gave me the expected value. I have noticed something though. When I go to edit in /publisher production URL field is cleared (empty) always no matter I save it before. Is this a bug or is this something intended to happen?

Comment: Hi Lolitha, I tried to reproduce. But I was unable. When I edit production URL, it is being pdated once I click on save. If its not working, then its a bug. Whats the browser and the version you are using. Also the OS? You should be able to update API values via publisher.

Comment: I used both firefox and chrome on Windows 7 environment. I'll try on Ubuntu and let you know. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Ushani, I tried with Ubuntu firefox setup but still I couldn't do it. Getting the same error. Also production url field keep blank whenever I tried to edit. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please try out the given sample? Pls check whether it works for you. If you think there is an issue pls open a jira, under https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APPFAC

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an online API management / gateway solution? If so, you should use [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/) instead.

Also, see the tutorials covering the scenarios you mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/).